# GitHub Actions step executed while it shouldn't, based on a conditional

Tags: bash, github, continuous-integration, github-actions

I have the following steps' sequence in a GitHub Actions job (first one is used more or less for debugging purposes

```yaml
env:
  FAIL_OUTCOME: 'fail'


      - name: debug
        shell: bash
        run: |
          echo "evaluation-1 result is ${{ steps.evaluation_1.outputs.evaluation-1-outcome }}
          echo "evaluation-2 result is ${{ steps.evaluation_2.outputs.evaluation-2-outcome }}
          echo $FAIL_OUTCOME

      - name: send slack failure
        if: ${{ steps.evaluation_1.outputs.evaluation-1-outcome }} == $FAIL_OUTCOME || ${{ steps.evaluation_2.outputs.evaluation-2-outcome }} == $FAIL_OUTCOME
        uses: rtCamp/action-slack-notify@v2
        env:
           ...


      - name: send slack success
        if: ${{ steps.evaluation_1.outputs.evaluation-1-outcome }} != $FAIL_OUTCOME && ${{ steps.evaluation_2.outputs.evaluation-2-outcome}} != $FAIL_OUTCOME
        uses: rtCamp/action-slack-notify@v2
        env:
          ...
```

Here is the outcome of the debug action:

```
  echo "evaluation-1 result is 
  echo "evaluation-2 result is fail
```

where it seems that first outcome is not set.

However, what puzzles me is that success action is also executed, i.e.

```
${{ steps.evaluation_1.outputs.evaluation-1-outcome }} != $FAIL_OUTCOME && ${{ steps.evaluation_2.outputs.evaluation-2-outcome}} != $FAIL_OUTCOME
```

becomes true. How is it possible?

To provide for more context, the outputs' assignment in previous steps are as follows:

```
echo "::set-output name=evaluation-2-outcome::$FAIL_OUTCOME"
```

Comment: Please show debug logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The straight answer to your question is that you are misusing the `$FAIL_OUTCOME` value in `if` statements.

There you need to use:

```
if: steps.evaluation_1.outputs.evaluation-1-outcome == env.FAIL_OUTCOME || steps.evaluation_2.outputs.evaluation-2-outcome == env.FAIL_OUTCOME
...
if: steps.evaluation_1.outputs.evaluation-1-outcome != env.FAIL_OUTCOME && steps.evaluation_2.outputs.evaluation-2-outcome != env.FAIL_OUTCOME
```

or:

```
if: ${{ steps.evaluation_1.outputs.evaluation-1-outcome == env.FAIL_OUTCOME || steps.evaluation_2.outputs.evaluation-2-outcome == env.FAIL_OUTCOME }}
...
if: ${{ steps.evaluation_1.outputs.evaluation-1-outcome != env.FAIL_OUTCOME && steps.evaluation_2.outputs.evaluation-2-outcome != env.FAIL_OUTCOME }}
```

Env variables can be accessed as $FAIL_OUTCOME only in `bash` scopes - everywhere else, you need to explicitly use `env.` prefix.

However, I would recommend doing it properly and not fighting with env variables combined with `set-output` madness - which has a lot of gotchas and it's hard to debug and maintain.

Slack success and failures can be easily handled by checking the output of the whole job:

```
 - name: send slack failure
   if: failure()

 - name: send slack success
   if: success()
```

If you want to communicate about failure of some steps only:

```
notify_failure:
    if: always() && !cancelled() && needs.check_failure_step.result != 'success'
    needs: check_failure_step
```

And instead of using `echo set-output::` just `exit 1` to fail a certain job.
Combining that with `needs` and jobs output values and `if: always()` you can achieve anything you want.

It gives you also a huge advantage of seeing which job has failed straight on workflow run summary without looking to its "output" or "debug" logs.